# Correction in the following delegate and method for invoking a control

Tags: c#, delegates, invokerequired

I need to access a listview's items in a DoWork event handler. For this the delegate and the method to invoke the listview what I wrote is:

```
delegate ListView itemDelegate(ListView bufferedListView1);

   private ListView getItems(ListView bufferedListView1)
   {
       if (bufferedListView1.InvokeRequired)
       {
         //  BeginInvoke(new itemDelegate(getItems));
             bufferedListView1.Invoke(new itemDelegate(getItems));
       }
       else
       {
           return bufferedListView1;
       }
   }
```

This is the first time I am working with invoking a control. So please let me know where I am wrong. One error that I get is `gsm_modem.Form1.getItems(System.Windows.Forms.ListView): not all code paths return a value`. I even guess that what I wrote might be wrong. Correction please..

Comment: The IF part of your statement doesn't return any value but the method expects to return a ListView. You'll need to either set a void return type on your method or return a listview.

Comment: @JamieDixon I do need to return the listview because I need to use it in another thread. So what should I write in BeginInvoke()?

Comment: You can't use BeginInvoke, Invoke is required here so you can get its return value.  Good hint what is so wrong about doing this kind of code, get UI values *before* you start a worker.  Getting them *while* the user is using the UI just produces random infrequent failure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-gui-from-another-thread-in-c

Comment: @HansPassant I have changed it to Contol.Invoke and I still get the same error. This might be an easy task `get UI values before you start a worker`, but I really cant understand how to do it. Please elaborate

Comment: @RaviPatel : sorry but that dint help me how to read a listview in other thread. A simpler code would be of much help

Comment: are you want text value of listviewitem?

Comment: @RaviPatel I want to acess the **complete listview** (In a `foreach loop`) in the `DoWork` handler of `Background worker`.

Comment: why you need whole listview if you want don't want to update it?

Comment: @RaviPatel I got nothing to update. I only need to access the listview in other thread. So please let me know how to go about

Comment: _"I want to acess the complete listview  [in] Background worker"_ - that's jus not going to work. ListView is a Control means main-thread-only. Try to separate Nodel and GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Ravi patel for the idea. This is what I did to solve the problem:

```
ListView listItems = new ListView();\\In global scope

foreach (ListViewItem item in bufferedListView1.Items)
{
   listItems.Items.Add((ListViewItem)item.Clone()); // Copied the bufferedListview's items that are to be accessed in other thread to another listview- listItems
}
```

Then used listItems in my other thread easily.

Comment: +1 for the `item.clone()` to copy one listview items to other

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

First create shared variable in global scope for your form.

```
List<string> listItems;
```

Now before calling RunWorkerAsync do following

```
listItems = new List<string>();
foreach (ListViewItem item in bufferedListView1.Items)
            {
                //If you want to add tag to list then you can use dictionary like Dictionary<string, object) listItems; and then add items as listItems.Add(item.Text, item.Tag); It only works if text is unique.
                listItems.Add(item.Text);
            }
bgw1.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Now read the list inside background worker using foreach.